# Using advance filter to populate listbox in userform

Tags: vba, excel

I have a master sheet where Column A contains "Customer Name" and Column B contains "Frequency" in which reports have to be sent to these Customers. Client names are repeated as shown in screenshot below
[image]

My userform has combobox which will take frequency details from column B and a list box which will populate data from Column A i.e. Unique client names. 
[image: Form screenshot]

After some research I could use Advance filter option to populate customer list box data using below code.

```
Dim arrUnqItems As Variant

        With Sheets("Data")

            .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , .Cells(1, .Columns.Count), True
            arrUnqItems = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(2, .Columns.Count), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).End(xlUp)).Value)
            .Columns(.Columns.Count).Clear

        End With

        Me.custList.Clear
        Me.custList.List = arrUnqItems

        Erase arrUnqItems
```

But this code for listbox is not filtering value based on Combobox selection but just displaying unique customer names. Can someone help here? Based on selection of combobox and listbox, I will then search the database to get additional details of the customer and populate in other parts of the forms.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Hard to visualise what you're doing.

Comment: Screenshot added.

Answer (score 0):

you have to write down a range for the `CriteriaRange` field:

```
    Dim freq As String
    freq = Combobox1.Value ' get the currently selected frequency (change "Combobox1" to your actual frequency combobox name)
    With Sheets("Data")
        .Cells(1, .Columns.Count - 2).Resize(2) = Application.Transpose(Array("Frequency", freq )) 'write the "CriteriaRange" in the third last column
        .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count - 2).Resize(2), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count - 1), True ' filter adopting the written "CriteriaRange" and paste filtered values from the second last column (two columns will be pasted: "Customer Name" and "Frequency")
        arrUnqItems = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(2, .Columns.Count - 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count - 1).End(xlUp)).Value) ' fill array of unique customer names from the second last column
        .Columns(.Columns.Count - 2).Resize(, 3).Clear
    End With
```